# Replace text with user input for number of replacements via CMD

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to develop a script that ask user to input the number of replacement he/she wants and do needful.
I have tried the following script but it is not working as expected.

My Inputs

```
Hello i am brow fox
brow fox is cunning one.
the real fox is brow`
```

I want to replace brow with brown and cunning with sly

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p num_replacements="How many search-and-replace operations do you want to perform? "

for /l %%n in (1,1,%num_replacements%) do (
    set /p "search%%n=Enter search string %%n: "
    set /p "replace%%n=Enter replace string %%n: "
)

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%f"
    set "tempfile=!filename!.tmp"
    (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("!filename!") do (
            set "line=%%i"
            for /l %%n in (1,1,%num_replacements%) do (
                set "search=!search%%n!"
                set "replace=!replace%%n!"
                set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
            )
            if defined line echo !line!
        ) >> "!tempfile!"
    )
    move /y "!tempfile!" "!filename!"
)

echo Done.
pause
```

But the output is not expected as it prints

```
line:=
line:=
line:=
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
```

`search` and `replace` are replaced by their respective values **when the outer loop** (`for %%f`) is encountered.

Since the inner loop changes these variables, they need to be accessed using `!search!`, but that leads to a syntax-confilct since `cmd` would be unable to anticipate what the programmer meant by

```
set "line=!line:!search!=!replace!!"
```

so, you simply invoke a subshell

```
CALL SET "line=%%line:!search!=!replace!%%"
```

- or you could use a subroutine.

Comment: CALL SET "line=%%line:!search!=!replace!%%"

This command absolutely worked for me, but I tried a multiline string for replacement there it says 
The system cannot find the file specified.
While the file is placed in the same folder and here is my string for replacement

<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2004" xmlns:btsedi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2005/EdiSchemaEditorExtension" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: Please include the appropriate source strings in your sample data, and add a listing of the source and replacement strings. Batch substitution is weak and will have problems with characters that are significant in the language like `!%=*:";` (not an exhaustine list). Perhaps a utility that is built for the job like`SED` may be better suited to your task.